# If-else statement based on timer

Tags: android, if-statement, timer

I've got a basic doorbell application, and I'm working out the last few kinks. One of the last ones I have is a vibrate function problem.

I've got an if-else statement which allows the phone to vibrate based upon a boolean. This works perfectly.

I want this function to be disabled while the phone is playing the sound I have.

I figure this would be done with an if-else statement, something like this:

```
if(dBell.isPlayingSound()) {
    // No vibrate
} else {
    Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibe.vibrate(500);
}
```

Either that, or based upon the timer I have set to change the picture, such as:

```
if(timer.hasNotExecuted) {
    // No vibrate
} else {
    Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibe.vibrate(500);
}
```

Here is my current if-else statement which makes the vibration toggle:

```
if (vibeOn) {
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    } else {
        // No vibration
    }
```

I need to get the vibration toggle to occur when the boolean is true and when the timer isn't done (or when the sound is not playing). So perhaps something like this:

```
if(vibeOn && timer.hasFinished) {
    Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibe.vibrate(500);
} else {
    // No vibration
}
```

Or

```
if(vibeOn && dBell.isNotPlaying) {
   ...
```

Something like that. I'm not sure what to do. I think I have the basic idea, but I don't know the code to make it happen.

Help!

Thanks!

Nathan

EDIT:

Got something to compile:

```
if (vibeOn && !dBell.isPlaying()) {
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    } else {
        // No vibration
    }
```

This is sitting inside of a method which is called when an ImageButton is clicked.

When the button is pressed, dBell is started right away, so I don't understand why the `!dBell.isPlaying()` restriction is having issues. It is constantly thinking that the sound is playing right.

I figured this might be happening because I tell the button to play the sound before it checks if it's playing.

So, I made the sound be played as such:

```
if (vibeOn && !dBell.isPlaying()) {
        Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate(500);
    } else {
        // No vibration
    }
    dBell.start();
```

This allows the sound to be played the first time, but every time after that, it doesn't work.

Found where the problem was!

I had implemented a `dBell.stop();` at the end of one of my timers, causing the MediaPlayer to break. I'll just play around with the MediaPlayer methods from here and see what works.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what you are using for playing the sound...mediaplayer,audiotrack or audiomanager...look in the API's of what class you're using

you're heading in the right direction though...i would take the approach of asking wheter song is playing or not

Comment: I'm using a MediaPlayer. I found some code which compiles, but when it is executed, the vibrate still doesn't occur. I'll attach the code to my original question as an edit.

Comment: ok its better to see what your actual problem is in code...maybe some explanation would be useful what you want to achive since i dont know what your doorbell app should do and when